# Multisite - user email activation links broken

Tags: multisite, user-registration

I am maintaining a large WP multisite network, but have to add all new users manually, because the email activation link that is sent out is always wrong.

If the domain is "**www.multisite.com**" and the sites are **/site1, /site2, site3,** etc, then the new user signup activation link generated is including the site folder like so:

https://www.multisite.com/**site1**/wp-activate.php?key=123456xxxx

But this link doesn't work, and leads to a "**critical error**" page. I believe the correct link is without the site folder, and works:

https://www.multisite.com/wp-activate.php?key=123456xxxx

I'm not sure if this is the intended behavior, (the user is only trying to register for /site1), and this link should work, or the link is wrong, and should point to the working default site link, (not site1)?

Any help/advice is appreciated!